# “Obst”, “Frucht”, “Früchte” – when to use which?

Tags: synonym, compound

*Das Obst*, *die Frucht* and *die Früchte* all refer to fruit but it seems like it’s used differently in various contexts.

For example:

- *Obstwasser* (for schnaps), but *Fruchtwasser* refers to *amniotic fluid*
- *Obstverkauf* but seldom *Fruchtverkauf*
- Both *Obstschale* and *Fruchtschale* refer to fruit bowl.
- Both *Obstsaft* and *Fruchtsaft* refer to the same thing.

When should we use *Obst* and when *Frucht*? What other common *Obst*/*Frucht* composite words are the same/different?

Comment: "Frucht" traditionally meant everything that could be harvested, so basically *yield* and was not restricted to fruit only. (See "Feldfrüchte", "Früchte der Arbeit", "die Früchte des Zorns")

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***Short answer:*** you refer to **Obst** as a culinary term (fruit substance), whereas **Frucht** is a biological / botanical word (for example a tree consists of the stem, leaves, fruits...).

***Long answer:*** It is not very easy to make a 100% clear difference between them. If you say:

> Ich esse gerne Obst.

and

> Ich esse gerne Früchte.

you mean the same thing. It is mostly a linguistic habit to prefer one of them in some fixed phrases. **Obst** refers more to culinary situations and **Frucht** refers more to biological terms, but you can often use them as synonyms *in the colloquial language*.

**Obst** implies *always* something *edible*. **Früchte** not always, for example rowan berries are not edible, but they are *Früchte* of rowan trees.

As Thorsten Dittmar says, **Früchte** can also be used in metaphorical sense, for example: ***Früchte seiner Arbeit***.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Obst refers more to cookin"? I don't use "Obst" for cooking. Do you confuse it with "Gemüse"?

Comment: Of course you do. **Obstkuchen**, **Obstsalat**, just to mention some of them. **Cooking** = **Preparing food**, you don't have to always use a cook for this.

Comment: Well, looking up "to cook", the important thing is that you **heat** the food. According to that definition, preparing a "Obstkuchen" could be considered cooking but I doubt that baking a cake is considered cooking by anyone. The "Obstsalat", however, is definitely not part of cooking. In conclusion, I still go with my point that "Obst" is *not* used for cooking.

Comment: Oh Mann, bist du vielleicht ein Erbsenzähler...

Comment: After all, I can agree with your answer now.

Comment: It should be added that *Frucht*  can also be used in a metaphorical sense, derived from the fact that you can harvest a fruit, as in *die Früchte seiner Arbeit*.

Comment: @Em1: off topic, but you can even say "I'm cooking up some ice cream here". At least in spoken American english, cooking really means just preparing, not boiling.

Comment: Die Leibesfrucht ist auch kein Obst.

Comment: @CarstenS: Außer das Kind ist eine Pflaume.

Comment: @CarstenS: Oder ein Früchtchen.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Barths answer it should be noted that neither are all *Früchte* *Obst*, nor is every *Obst* a *Frucht*.

For example:

Strawberries are considered *Obst*, while they are not a *Frucht* in the biological sense. Ananas is considered *Obst*, but is not a *Frucht*, but a *Fruchtverband*.

On the other hand, peppers (*Paprika*) and tomatoes are *Früchte* but are not considered *Obst*.

Wikipedia for example [defines](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Obst&oldid=143521393) Obst as:

> Obst ist ein Sammelbegriff der für den Menschen roh genießbaren meist wasserhaltigen Früchte oder Teilen davon (**beispielsweise Samen**), die von Bäumen, Sträuchern und mehrjährigen Stauden stammen.

*Frucht* is a biological term defined as a part of a flowering plant that derives from the flower (more or less).

Answer (score 7):

Frucht ist ein botanischer Begriff. Obst eher ein kulinarischer. Früchte ist die Pluralform.

[Im Duden gibt es drei verschiedene Bedeutungen für das Wort "Frucht"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Frucht). Ich zitiere nur die erste Bedeutung, da sie zu Ihrer Frage passt:

> - aus dem Fruchtknoten entstehender Teil der Pflanze, der den Samen bis zur Reife umschließt (und der bei bestimmten Bäumen, Sträuchern und anderen Pflanzen essbar ist)
> - (landschaftlich) Getreide

Obst ist eher kulinarischer Natur und wird im [Duden als "essbare, meist saftige Früchte bestimmter Bäume und Sträucher" beschrieben.](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Obst)

Übrigens: Obst gibt es nur im Singular. Im Duden wird Obst auch als Synonym für Früchte beschrieben. Sprich Obst Numerus Singular, doch umfasst mehrere Früchte.

Hoffentlich konnte ich helfen.

PS! Ich habe meine Antwort auf Deutsch verfasst, weil Sie ein Interesse an Deutsch mit ihrer Frage bekundet haben. Und da Sie bereits Ihre Frage auf Englisch beantwortet bekamen, dachte ich, ich antworte auf Deutsch. Damit Sie eine Antwort auf Englisch und eine auf Deutsch besitzen.

Comment: Willkommen! http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/36/umgangsformen-du-oder-sie

Answer (score 5):

*Obst* and *Frucht/Früchte* are the same thing in the supermarket. *Obst* has no plural, which makes it easier to use, it also has no second meaning, so I would stick to that for the time being.

- Obststand = Früchtestand (fruit stand)
- Obst essen = Früchte essen
- Obstkuchen = Früchtekuchen (selten)
- Obstfliege = Fruchtfliege
- Obstsalat = Fruchtsalat
- ...

*Obstwasser* is not the same as *Fruchtwasser*, and *die Obstbar* (n.) is not the same as *fruchtbar* (adj.). But this is the same in English, the terms *Fruchtwasser/fruchtbar* come from the same origin as "Be fruitful and multiply". God did not tell the people to hang fruit around their neck while using a calculator, did he?

Comment: My family distinguishs between Obstkuchen (strawberry cake) und Früchtebrot (e.g. banana bread), but I've never heard Früchtekuchen.

Answer (score -1):

We learned at school that *Obst* always contains a stone (cherry, apricot peach, etc.) but fruit contain seeds.

Comment: Das gilt zumindest für Steinobst.

Comment: @userunknown Und es beantwortet die Frage nur über Umwege und nicht überzeugend („Wann sage ich Obst, wann Frucht?“ „Sag Obst, wenn es Steine hat, Frucht, wenn es Kerne hat.“).
Welcome to GermanSE, applexi. Could you add some more details to your answer (e. g. that there’s a biological distinction between fruit with stones and seeds, which is not necessarily reflected in colloquial speech)?

Answer (score -3):

There is one more case which I find more important that a comment: *Obst*, being a bit more specifically "sweet" than fruits, is used to designate a complementary concept of *Gemüse* (vegetables), while *Früchte* is usually not used in such a distinction.

I.e., while calling something a *Frucht- und Gemüseabteilung* is not incorrect per se, *Obst- und Gemüseabteilung* would be much more idiomatic (at least in Austria).

Comment: Da sich die Mengen Obst und Früchte überlappen kann nicht das eine süßer sein als das andere. Und von einem Gegenteil von Gemüse kann auch nicht gesprochen werden.

Comment: Wenn du eine Menge durch den Durchschnitt definierst dann kannst du über eine Menge und ihre Teilmenge vergleichende Aussagen machen. z.B Das wohlhabendste Prozent der Bevölkerung verdient x mal so viel wie die Gesamtbevölkerung. Natürlich ist das Prozent teil der Bevölkerung.